# Swift 2.0 : 'enumerate' is unavailable: call the 'enumerate()' method on the sequence

Tags: swift, swift2

Just downloaded Xcode 7 Beta, and this error appeared on `enumerate` keyword.

```
for (index, string) in enumerate(mySwiftStringArray)
{

}
```

Can anyone help me overcome this ?

Also, seems like `count()` is no longer working for counting length of `String`.

```
let stringLength = count(myString)
```

On above line, compiler says :

> 'count' is unavailable: access the 'count' property on the collection.

Has Apple has released any programming guide for Swift 2.0 ?

Comment: I also miss a programming guide.

Comment: In Xcode 7.1.1 the error message is pretty descriptive:  'enumerate' is unavailable: call the 'enumerate()' method on the sequence

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Many global functions have been replaced by *protocol extension methods*,
a new feature of Swift 2, so `enumerate()` is now an extension method
for `SequenceType`:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func enumerate() -> EnumerateSequence<Self>
}
```

and used as

```
let mySwiftStringArray = [ "foo", "bar" ]
for (index, string) in mySwiftStringArray.enumerate() {
   print(string) 
}
```

And `String` does no longer conform to `SequenceType`, you have to
use the `characters` property to get the collection of Unicode
characters. Also, `count()` is a protocol extension method of 
`CollectionType` instead of a global function:

```
let myString = "foo"
let stringLength = myString.characters.count
print(stringLength)
```

**Update for Swift 3:** `enumerate()` has been renamed to `enumerated()`:

```
let mySwiftStringArray = [ "foo", "bar" ]
for (index, string) in mySwiftStringArray.enumerated() {
    print(string)
}
```

Comment: Swift is actually looking like a nice language now!

Answer (score 5):

There was an update for Swift 2 on using enumerate().

Instead of `enumerate(...)`, people should use

... `.enumerate()`

The reason is that many global functions have been replaced by protocol extension methods and they will get an enumerate error.

Hope this helps.
All the best.
n

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old thread but I've just been messing around with Swift 2.0 and Playgrounds and I came across the same problem I thought I'd share a solution which uses the enumerate() method for a String

```
// This line works in Swift 1.2
// for (idx, character) in enumerate("A random string, it has a comma.")

// Swift 2.x
let count = inputString.characters

for (idx, character) in count.enumerate() where character == "," {

    // Do something with idx
}
```

Hope this helps

Thanks 
Kai